# How to prevent soft keyboard from showing on click on EditText?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, keyboard

I'm making a Android Calculator app and I'm stuck in a problem when I type on EditText It open the soft keyboard but I want to make user use the calculator keyboard given on screen and don't use the system's one! The main problem is the original system soft keyboard is opening when click on EditText.

How can I resolve the problem?
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-programmatically-hide-android-soft-keyboard/

Comment: Thanks @jaikhambhayta I solved the problem now